# Is there a way to access or scrape dynamically changing data or graphs from sites such as https://finance.yahoo.com/ in python3 or python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib, yahoo-finance

I was trying to **scrape** some stock related data from the graphs given on sites like yahoo finance  I am unable to access any dynamic data . I have tried **scraping** sites like flip-kart and there I had no such problem , so what I really want to ask is  that , is there a way to access stock related data of companies from https://finance.yahoo.com/ without using any API.

[image]

```
enter code here 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from urllib2 import urlopen


url="https://www.bloombergquint.com/stock/901145/indian-oil-corp"

client=urlopen(url)
html_page=client.read()
client.close()

page=soup(html_page,"html.parser")
html_page2=page.findAll("div",{"class":"widget-content"})[0]
chart_link= html_page2.iframe['data-src']
client2=urlopen(chart_link)
html_page3=client2.read()
client2.close()
page2=soup(html_page3,"html.parser")

x1=page2.findAll("div",{"class":"bbcard"})[0]
x2=x1.div.div
x3=x2.findAll("div",{"class":"main-price-graph"})[0]
print x3
```

Comment: Post your code of what you have done so far then maybe someone can assist.

Comment: Look at class name commonalities on the elements in the page.

Comment: I have similar code for bloombergquint in python 2 and there I was scrapping the graph but same problem occurred  so I am providing the code , some screenshot and the link to site :
https://www.bloombergquint.com/stock/901145/indian-oil-corp b